# Why I cannot use iterator again in Scala

Tags: scala

Two questions on iterators

**Question 1)** Why is an iterator implemented in such a manner that it cannot be reused? Is it achieve memory optimisation?

```
scala> while (it.hasNext) println(it.next)
1
2
3
4
5

scala> while (it.hasNext) println(it.next)

scala>
```

**Question 2)** How is the iterator implemented to achieve this behavior? Is it that the `iterator` points to only one element of the collection and if there is a next element then the previous value of the iterator is overwritten? Something like a LinkedList with logic similar to `if (node->next != null) node = node->next`

Comment: Think about an iterator that represents a stream of random numbers or user inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noticed that method `hasNext()`? That method tells you when "everything was iterated". Why do you expect the method to return true again, after it told you: "you saw all the elements" before? How should the iterator "know" that you decided to re-visit all (or some?!) entries *again*?!

The whole point of (most) iterator implementations is: you use it to "iterate" on something in a certain order.

The whole concept focuses on that "iterating in a certain order". Your idea of re-using the *same* iterator is thus something that doesn't "fit" the underlying idea of iterators.

Of course, you could create your own iterator implementation that allows for "resetting" the iterator. But as said: that would be something that you need to implement yourself.